# Return the maximum value from a set of values separated by a consistent delimiter in a column in excel

Tags: vba, excel

Example Input:

```
Length
24:00
24:00
00:36
00:36
24:36
Length
08:00
08:00
08:00
Length
08:00
08:00
01:16
01:16
09:16
Length
08:00
08:00
00:42
00:42
08:42
```

I have a list of names these times are paired with and need to see the total number, ideally I could restructure the template of the system spitting this data out but I don't have access to that part of the system so I need to find a way to parse the largest number out.  I would just take the last value in the group but I don't know how to define an array from the sets dynamically since the length of each set varies.

Desired output would be a list of the numbers, one per section, without the delimiter included:

```
24:36
08:00
09:16
08:42
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Provide any code you have attempted so far.

Comment: You haven't clearly explained what your problem is.

Comment: Is this being done in VBA or excel? if VBA please add tag, in either case please provide same layout

Comment: My problem is that I frankly don't know where to start, I'm researching how to go forward but I thought I'd get the ball rolling with any suggestions here.  The code I have written so far is mostly just specific selections to get the list clean enough to attempt what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions, you should be able to set an empty string and a max variable, and then loop through the column, checking if the value is "length". If it is length, add the max to the string and reset the max to zero.

Something like:

```
dim max as integer 
dim i as integer
dim col as integer
dim ret as String
max = 0
col = 1 'Assume A for now
i = 1
ret = ""
while not sheets("sheet1").cells(i,col).value = ""
   if sheets("sheet1").cells(i,col).value > max 'Check for max
       max = sheets("sheet1").cells(i,col).value
   end if
   if sheets("sheet1").cells(i,col).value = "length" 'Check for delimeter
      ret = ret + max + vbCrLf 'convert to string, add a newline.
      max = 0
   end if
   i = i + 1
wend
return ret
```

It's rough and untested, but should give you a general idea of a strategy.

Of course, this won't work for a value like 23:40, you'd have to either make a custom class and override an isGreater() function, or else split it into two integers, one before : and one after.

Comment: Hey, I thought of that issue just before you brought up the value type issue, converting the entire column to decimal and omitting the Lengths for a blank cell as the delimiter was my solution.

Comment: D'oh. Missed the obvious solution of using floats and changing `:` to `.` +1 for that.